# MySQL throws error but works - PhpMyAdmin without error

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this query on my MySQL Database - with mysql_query it throws me an error but the data is still properly inserted into the table. If I enter it in PhpMyAdmin it works without error.

```
INSERT INTO `kommentare` VALUES(NULL,'1','MyName','MyEmail','MyText','2014-08-05');
```

PHP :

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($name); 
$email = mysql_escape_string($email); 
$kommentar = mysql_escape_string($kommentar); 
$datum = mysql_escape_string($datum); 
$reiseid = str_replace("/", "", $reiseid); 
$query = "INSERT INTO kommentare VALUES(NULL,'" . $reiseid . "','" . $name . "','" . $email . "','" . $kommentar . "','" . $datum . "');";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
echo $query;
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

How is that possible? I am experienced with MySQL but this wrecks my nerves - it works but says it doesn't?!

UPDATE:

It just happens when I have more than one entry in the table. ANd even if I remove all the ' it gives me the same error, saying I should check near the '

Comment: Maybe any hidden special characters at the beginning of your query string? Try typing it in manually instead of copy-paste.

Comment: No, there are none :(

Comment: @Liam Schnell Your field `NULL` is `id`? PRIMARY_KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: It looks like you are using backticks around `kommentare` instead of single quotes (`'`)

Comment: add the php code may be something related to PHP code

Comment: It's because you have the query spanning multiple lines. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155489/mysql-the-right-syntax-to-use-near-at-line-1-error

Comment: @ElGavilan: Backticks are correctly used.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Yes, right. Normally I just type '' instead of NULL

Comment: @ElGavilan - You use backticks for non-string values like column names and aliases in sql. Not usually required and I avoid them, but it helps offset variable input from internal syntax.

Comment: @Anthony So close. I had the code like this, changed it to this but it won't work anyway. It throws an error but the data is properly inserted.

*$name = mysql_escape_string($name);
    $email = mysql_escape_string($email);
    $kommentar = mysql_escape_string($kommentar);
    $datum = mysql_escape_string($datum);
    $reiseid = str_replace("/", "", $reiseid);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `kommentare` VALUES(NULL,'" . $reiseid . "','" . $name . "','" . $email . "','" . $kommentar . "','" . $datum . "');";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $query;*

Comment: @LiamSchnell But value `'1'`? What is it?

Comment: @LucasHenrique An integer for a relational database :)

Comment: It only happens after I've entered a first entry. When there is one entry in the database it throws an error, if the table is empty it works once.

Comment: @LiamSchnell So your field is not AUTO_INCREMENT? Being PRIMARY KEY works the first, but the second generates the error.

Comment: @LucasHenrique - That wouldn't throw a syntax error, it would throw a duplicate key error.

Comment: @LiamSchnell You're right.

Comment: It is AI and PRIMARY KEY - yeah, this is why I am so angry. Those damn MySQL errors are fuc*ing useless (:

Comment: @LiamSchnell Can I post an answer to close the question?

Comment: Well, if the answer works, sure :) Still not working on my end

Comment: @LiamSchnell Sorry, I thought I had achieved with the Primary Key and AI. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the first column is a auto-increment primary key, you don't pass it `NULL`, you pass it `DEFAULT`:

```
INSERT INTO kommentare VALUES 
(DEFAULT,'$reiseid','$name','$email','$kommentar','$datum');
```

But really you should instead be naming your columns and skipping those that you don't have a value for:

```
INSERT INTO kommentare 
(reiseid, name, email, kommentar, datum)
VALUES
('$reiseid','$name','$email','$kommentar','$datum');
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

My id has been passed not as 1 but as 1/ for some reason. This caused MySQL to crash although it was not shown to me. I replace the / with "" now and everything works fine!

Comment: Not really a solution, since we don't know why that value got in the query or how to properly avoid it, not to mention you specifically said you had a line of code `$reiseid = str_replace("/", "", $reiseid); ` when the problem started. I suspect you'll run into more issues and frustrations when the problem pops up again "for some reason"