# "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm trying to execute an insert query. **It works when I directly copy and paste it to the mysql command prompt, but fails when I execute it from Python.** I'm getting this error with MySQLdb (also tried using _mysql directly and get the same error).

The error is the same as this question, but the answer does not work for my problem (my query is on a single line): [MySQL the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155489/mysql-the-right-syntax-to-use-near-at-line-1-error)

```
query = """INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES (%f) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE %s=%f"""%(table_name,measurement_type,value,measurement_type,value)
print query 
cur.execute(query)
```

Result (it prints the query, which when copied directly into MySQL command prompt executes fine, and then crashes):

```
INSERT INTO D02CA10B13E5$accelerometer_X(periodic) VALUES (79.000000) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE periodic=79.000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "collect_data.py", line 145, in <module>
process_data_array(data_bytes[start:start+sensor_packet_size])
File "collect_data.py", line 105, in process_data_array
record_data(MAC,sensor_name,"X",code_name,X,cur)
File "collect_data.py", line 58, in record_data
cur.execute(query)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
```

I tried turning on profiling because I can't seem be able to access _last_executed from my cursor (something others have suggested). It seems that my cursor does not have this property (was it removed?).

```
query = """INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES (%f) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE %s=%f"""%(table_name,measurement_type,value,measurement_type,value)
print query 
#cur.execute(query)
try:
    cur.execute(query)
except:
    cur.execute('show profiles')
    for row in cur:
        print row
    cur.execute("set profiling = 0")
    exit()
```

This shows me an incomplete query:

```
INSERT INTO D02CA10B13E5$accelerometer_X(periodic) VALUES (80.000000) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE periodic=80.000000
(1L, 5.925e-05, 'INSERT INTO D02CA10B13E5')
```

Some suggest splitting the query into multiple lines (which contradicts the  suggestion in the link I posted above). Anyway, it narrows the search to one line (apparently the Python module doesn't like either my table name or column name which are on the third line)

```
query = "INSERT \nINTO \n%s(%s) \nVALUES \n(%f) \nON \nDUPLICATE \nKEY \nUPDATE %s=%f"%(table_name,measurement_type,value,measurement_type,value)
print query 
cur.execute(query)
```

Result:

```
INSERT 
INTO 
D02CA10B13E5$accelerometer_X(periodic) 
VALUES 
(80.000000) 
ON 
DUPLICATE 
KEY 
UPDATE periodic=80.000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "collect_data.py", line 145, in <module>
process_data_array(data_bytes[start:start+sensor_packet_size])
File "collect_data.py", line 105, in process_data_array
record_data(MAC,sensor_name,"X",code_name,X,cur)
File "collect_data.py", line 58, in record_data
cur.execute(query)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3")
```

Again, this query executes fine on MySQL, so I'm not sure what's going on here in Python. Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm suspicious of the "$" symbol. I suggest you try escaping it, (use "\$") or see what happens if you run a query on a table without "$" in the name.

Comment: Tried removing "$", didn't help. It is a permissible schema object character: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html But thanks, it was worth checking.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so '' in the MySQL error apparently referred to a \0 character that got appended to my table name. This was not visible as you can see for yourself:

```
>>> print chr(0)

>>> print "hello" + chr(0)
hello
```

The \0 character is completely invisible and doesn't get copied onto the clipboard from the terminal (so it worked when pasted onto the MySQL console). Sneaky!

I found this out by comparing string lengths with expected string lengths and finding a difference of 1 character that was invisible to my eyes. The \0 character came about in my Python code when I read the string (sensor ID) from a socket (the application on the other end was a C program that was appending these \0 characters).

Hope my answer saves someone else a lot of trouble!